# Excel 2010 formula to merge columns in separate sheets

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets populated with data that are related. The relation is by email address.

How can I append specific columns(retail store, store code) from sheet 2 to sheet 1, based on the email address relation? Is there a way? Thanks.

Comment: try googling an example for an excel formula called `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/look-up-values-with-vlookup-index-or-match-HA102809472.aspx?CTT=1

I know it says that it is for Excel 2013, but the functions explained in there will work in any version of Excel